# Disable scrolling in UICollectionView and resize it to wrap all cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UICollectionView` in a `UITableViewCell`. So the hierarchy is like this:

> UITableView -> UITableViewCell -> UICollectionView - >
>   UICollectionViewCell

What I want to achieve here is disable scrolling in `UICollectionView`, and make it look like a big list of items. All content are created dynamically. So how do I resize an `UICollectionView` depending on its cells. Its height should be equal to total of all `UICollectionViewCells`.

Thanks!

Edit: I managed to disable scrolling and it worked. Then tried to resize the cell but it doesen't seem to do anything:

```
cell.viewscollectionview.scrollEnabled = false
cell.viewscollectionview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width, 800)
```

Comment: Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift), might help you. You'll end up having two dynamic heights: 1) `UICollectionView`'s height based on the number of `UICollectionViewCells` x their heights; 2) `UITableViewCell`'s height should be equals `UICollectionView`'s once it has updated it's height.

Comment: So how do I change the height of UIcollectionView, no matter what I do it stays same as the one set in storyboard.

Comment: Does it have any constraints in storyboard ?

Comment: Not sure about it, i clicked on it and selected remove constraints.

Comment: and are you sure that the frame of collection view doesnt change ?

Comment: Does your table has many cells, and each of the cells have different collections? So the table scrolls but the collections don't? I'm trying to figure out an answer for you but always end up having other questions. Can you post the code and maybe a screenshot of your IB that shows how the view is being designed?

Answer (score 2):

Try using autolayouts.
Use the collection view height constraint.Keep it constant in the beginning.Later as you add data to the cell adjust the height of collection view by changing the constant of the height constraint.

Answer (score 2):

You must calculate UICollectionView height inside `heightForRowAt` in tableView delegate.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    // constants, should be initialized somewhere else
    let totalItem: CGFloat = 20
    let totalCellInARow: CGFloat = 3
    let cellHeight: CGFloat = 120

    let collViewTopOffset: CGFloat = 10
    let collViewBottomOffset: CGFloat = 10

    let minLineSpacing: CGFloat = 5

    // calculations
    let totalRow = ceil(totalItem / totalCellInARow)
    let totalTopBottomOffset = collViewTopOffset + collViewBottomOffset
    let totalSpacing = CGFloat(totalRow - 1) * minLineSpacing   // total line space in UICollectionView is (totalRow - 1)
    let totalHeight  = (itemHeight * totalRow) + totalTopBottomOffset + totalSpacing

    return totalHeight 
}
```

For full tutorial, you can read it here: https://medium.com/@adinugroho/fixed-height-uicollectionview-inside-uitableview-79f24657d08f